# Python regular expression to validate name with one or more words?

Tags: python, regex

I need a regular expression  in python to check if a name is valid. That name should be one word or several words joined with a whitespace. It should also allow some special characters from spanish like á é í ó ú ñ and also (') and (-) Some valid names should be:
"Roberto de la Vega Núñez"
"Ramón Pérez"
"María Cristina"
"Ernest"
"O'Riordan"
"Griffin-Joyner"
Of course it should not accept numbers nor other characters like &^%#$@!~
What regex should I use?

Comment: Relevant: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: The pattern ``^[-'áéíóúña-zA-Z ]+$`` does not match ``Rober434t de3 dg5#``. What exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: I am using that regex in odoo to check if a name contains invalid characters. This code should raise a warning if the name " Rober434t de3 dg5#" is typed. But its is acepting it as valid   <<"if not re.match(r"^[\-'áéíóúña-zA-Z ]+$", record.name)">>  it raises a warning

Comment: I found the solution "^[\-'a-zA-Z áéíóúñ ]+$". But it was failing due a bug in my odoo code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one: `^[\-'a-zA-Z ]+$`. It's pretty simple, you should carefully read [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for `re` module.

Here is a driver code:

```py
import re


def check_name(name: str):
    return re.match(r"^[\-'a-zA-Z ]+$", name) is not None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert check_name('Griffin-Joyner') == True
    assert check_name("O'Riordan") == True
    assert check_name("Ernest") == True
    assert check_name("Roberto de la Vega") == True
    assert check_name("1Roberto de la Vega") == False
    assert check_name("Foo@bar") == False
```

Comment: It should also allow some special characters from spanish like á é í ó ú ñ. I have already tried with "^[-'áéíóúña-zA-Z ]+$" but it allow names like "Rober434t de3 dg5#"

Comment: @tico1993 I can't reproduce this. Your regex works for me with Python 3 on Linux and `"Rober434t de3 dg5#"` returns `False`.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your case passing all the five you have mentioned

```
re.match(r'[a-zA-Z\'\-\s]+$', name)
```